# Office Document Preview on hover open in Office 2010

Tags: office-integration, office, preview

I am wondering how I can make the Office Document Preview within SharePoint 2016 open in the application (Office 2010). The feature to open in the browser is working but how can I get the preview to view in the application. In my case Office 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for the Preview to view in the client application. You can have the document itself open in the client application by default by controlling the behavior via the Document Library settings. This is done under Advanced settings -> Open in the client application.